# ObjectAnimator with a custom property does not call the property setter

Tags: android, animation, kotlin

I want to animate custom view position with custom property, like this:

```
class ProgressFab : ImageView {

    // constructors ... etc

    val path = Path()

    init {
        path.moveTo(0f, 0f)
        path.lineTo(700f, 500f)
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public fun setFubPosition(path: FloatArray) {
        this.x = path[0]
        this.y = path[1]
    }

    fun startMotion() {
        val animator = ObjectAnimator.ofMultiFloat(this, "fubPosition", path)
        animator.duration = 5000

        animator.addUpdateListener {
//(1)       this.x = (it?.animatedValue as FloatArray)[0]
//(2)       this.y = (it?.animatedValue as FloatArray)[1]
            invalidate()
        }

        animator.start()
    }
}
```

After calling `startMotion()` animator starts but `setFubPosition(path: FloatArray)` not called. If I uncomment (1) and (2) all works fine.

This is decompiled kotlin bytecode (all looks fine):

```
public final void setFubPosition(@NotNull float[] path) {
    Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(path, "path");
    this.setX(path[0]);
    this.setY(path[1]);
}
```

If I try to animate custom property with `ofFloat` method, property setter works fine:

```
val animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this, "fubPosition", 0f, 100f);
```

Is it possible in kotlin to automatically change property with property setter using `ofMultiFloat` or `ofMultiInt` method?

Comment: what do you see on the logcat after calling `animator.start()`?

Comment: Nothing about animation. Because animation starts and if I add `Log.d()` into `addUpdateListener` and show `animatedValue` it'll shown in logcat.

Comment: dont you have any `Method <your method here> () with type <types>   
 not found on target class <your target class here>` warning?

Comment: No, nothing (after clearing logcat and running method there is nothing similar)

Comment: check the logcat again when calling `ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this, "foo", 0f, 100f);` - do you see any `Method setFoo with type float not found on target class ...`? if you dont see it your logcat is filtering out some logs

Comment: With `ObjectAnimator.ofFloat` all works fine and setter is called.

Comment: I'am sorry, with `foo` there is warning: `Method setFoo() with type float not found on target class`

Comment: ok, so its strange that you dont see anything on the logcat and the method is not called... what avd version are you running that code? i remember i got problems with it on 4.4 avd

Comment: I am using Nexus 5X with 8.1.0, physical device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of [`ObjectAnimator.ofMultiFloat()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator#ofMultiFloat(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20android.graphics.Path)) you get

> In this variation, the coordinates are float x and y coordinates used in the first and second parameter of the setter, respectively.

So an array is not supported as parameter for the property, but multiple parameters are. Just change the signature of the setter to reflect this requirement:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public fun setFubPosition(x: Float, y: Float) {
    this.x = x
    this.y = y
}
```

Comment: Extremely very simple! In java this works fine but in kotlin code lint show error: `The setter for this property does not match the expected signature (public void setFubPosition(float[] arg) (Property setter here)`. And I didn't run this code because of this error message. But now I run and all works (error msg still exist)! Thank You!